# Refreshing one form on close of another or via a button click on another form

Tags: c#, winforms, button, refresh

My program allows the user to edit the data in a database. This works by showing the user the "product" on one form and then asks them to insert the correct amount of stock on another.

I am trying to make it so that the first form with the "product" is refreshed to show the amended numbers from the second form with either the closure of the second or via a button click on the second.

I unfortunately have no knowledge of how to do this.

I know that it's not:

```
frm1 f1 = new frm1(this);
f1.Show();
```

Code for amend form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace InventoryManager
{
    public partial class frmAdjustment : Form
    {
        frmAmendStock _main;

        public string enteredSKU { get; set; }

        public frmAdjustment(frmAmendStock main)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _main = main;
        }        

        private void frmAdjustment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.AcceptButton = btnSubmit;
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection())
            {

                connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Other\Documents\University Work\USB\Individual Project\Artefact\InventoryManager\InventoryManager\stock.mdb";
                connect.Open();

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE items SET Stock = @stock, Stock_Counted = @counted WHERE SKU LIKE '" +enteredSKU+"'", connect);
                string units = txtAmount.Text;

                    if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(units))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the correct amount of units.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@stock", OleDbType.Integer, 5).Value = txtAmount.Text;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@counted", OleDbType.Integer, 5).Value = txtAmount.Text;

                            try
                            {
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                MessageBox.Show("Stock Adjusted", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                                txtAmount.Clear();

                                connect.Close();
                                this.Close();
                            }
                            catch (Exception expe)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(expe.ToString());
                                connect.Close();
                            }
                      }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a public property "Stock" in the second form and set its value if the user clicks the "Ok" button
2. Open the second form as a modal dialog
3. When the second form closes, check if the "Ok" button was pressed and if so, get the value from the "stock" property. Remember you still have a reference to this form after it's been closed.

Example :`

```
 if (f1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK){
     var stock = f1.Stock;
  }
```

Makes sense ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have added the code of my amendment form into the post, hope it helps.

Comment: Add a public property called Stock to frmAdjustment. Then, after the  data gets saved in the button_submit_click event, add this line : this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;  From frmAmendStock you'll be able to access the Stock property of the frmAdjustment.